# Tensorflow C++ API: Difference between `fetch_outputs` and `run_outputs` in `Session::Run`

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Hello TensorFlow experts,

I found in the C++ API signature of Session::Run as below

```
Status Run(
  const RunOptions & run_options,
  const FeedType & inputs,
  const std::vector< Output > & fetch_outputs,
  const std::vector< Operation > & run_outputs,
  std::vector< Tensor > *outputs,
  RunMetadata *run_metadata
) const
```

What is the difference between `fetch_outputs` and `run_outputs`? Per my understanding at present, `run_outputs` is the final operation node evaluated during the run and `fetch_outputs` are all the intermediate values generated when evaluating `run_outputs`. And it looks the results of `fetch_outputs` are stored into `outputs` when function returns. Is it also possible that I got the value of `run_outputs` as well (or `run_outputs` has been included into `outputs`)?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is mostly correct. `fetch_outputs` is a list of tensors that will be computed and returned in `outputs`. `run_outputs` is a list of operations that we need to run (e.g. update some variable) but don't care about their outputs.

I am not sure what you mean by "Is it also possible that I got the value of run_outputs as well". If you want the resulting tensors from operations in `run_outputs`, just include these tensors in `fetch_outputs`. They are not included in `outputs` - that is their whole purpose.